# Nodejs server/client socket connection with engine.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, engine.io

I am trying to get a simple socket connection established between an engine.io socket listener which is listening on port 8888 and a javascript client which is running in a plain index.html

It looked rather straight forward to accomplish this task but somehow I am unable to get a xhr-polling client connected properly. It connects, since the client number increases but the onopen event is never triggered on the client side. Instead the client count on the server side just keeps increasing infinitely and the client is never receiving any messages from the server - nor is the server receiving any messages from the client.

It all works perfectly with the websocket transport, but I need xhr-polling to work as well.

**app.js**

```
var engine = require('engine.io');
var server = engine.listen(8888);

server.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log(server.clientsCount);
    socket.send('never received by client'); // << xhr-polling client does not receive
    socket.on('message', function (msg) {
        if ('echo' == msg) socket.send(msg);
    });
});
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="engine.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = eio('ws://localhost:8888/'); << starts polling immediately like crazy
    socket.onopen = function(){
        console.log('never fired'); << never sent to console
        socket.onmessage = function(data){};
        socket.onclose = function(){};
    };
</script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**client console**

```
GET http://localhost:8888/engine.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling 200 OK 280ms engine.io.js (Zeile 1585)
GET http://localhost:8888/engine.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling 200 OK 1ms engine.io.js (Zeile 1585)
GET http://localhost:8888/engine.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling 200 OK 1ms engine.io.js (Zeile 1585)
GET http://localhost:8888/engine.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling 200 OK 1ms engine.io.js (Zeile 1585)
GET http://localhost:8888/engine.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling 200 OK 0ms engine.io.js (Zeile 1585)
GET http://localhost:8888/engine.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling 200 OK 0ms engine.io.js (Zeile 1585)
GET http://localhost:8888/engine.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling 200 OK 0ms engine.io.js (Zeile 1585)
```

Comment: Having exactly the same problem. My `engine.io.js` file from [github](https://github.com/LearnBoost/engine.io-client) has a lot of dependencies that are not available on the client side. Don`t know I it is the correct one. Is the `/lib` folder required on the client side?

Comment: As far as I am aware of it - or what i assumed until now - the provided `engine.io.js` is already a bundled lib, similar to what you get when you run the nodejs client code thru the browserify tool.

Comment: Yes, the readme also says so. However, if you look at the current available `engine.io.js` version here: https://github.com/LearnBoost/engine.io-client/blob/master/engine.io.js then you see already two requirements (lines 8 and 12) that should not be available on the client side. For some reason it still connects without any error and the socket.id is returned, but about 150 times per minute from a single window.

Comment: I've replaced the `engine.io.js` which I copy/pasted from the master-branch on github with the one from the 0.9.0 release and it works now all of a sudden. Rather stupid from my side to use the dev version.

Comment: Thanks, that file seems to work. I am still wondering though, what lines like `module.exports =  require('./lib/');` are there for, if Readme claims it is the standalone version. I do not use Browserify, it seems to be pretty useless.

Answer (score 0):

If your HTML and static files (JS) are server from another domain (localhost:80 for example, as port == another "domain").
Then due to security reasons it might deny WebSockets or other traffic to happen due to CORS reasons.

Use Network tab in Dev Tools of your favourite browser, to check what is going on and if any requests fails as well as their headers.